# Getting WebElement while using another WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to get elements inside another extracted element using selenium. But I'm getting unexpected results. For example the code below returns the same "data-time" and the tweet time in the loop. Notice how the "data-item-id" is different but the "data-time" is the same. I'm trying to get the "data-time" related to the element in the loop. Any idea what my mistake is?

```
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/CNN");

    List<WebElement> tweets = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'js-stream-item')]"));

    for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(tweets.get(i).getAttribute("data-item-id"));
        WebElement tweetTime = tweets.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/small/a/span"));
        System.out.println(tweetTime.getAttribute("data-time"));
        System.out.println(tweetTime.getText());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
    }
```

Output

```
964597320301121536
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966636880702840834
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966638057217757184
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966636332721360896
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966633486797942784
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966630573740523520
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966627896474460160
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966624849732034560
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966622030526402561
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966611062052343808
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966605886792830976
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966604093719482373
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966602318522265600
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966600547364233216
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966598713903865857
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966594943216242688
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966591153700245505
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966587390805577730
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966587263147741185
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966585227618541568
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
966583600673099777
1518812897
Feb 16
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: My guess would be that `tweets.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/small/a/span")` always refers to the same tweet, and thus the same tweet time. Any reason why you are not getting the tweet time from the original `tweet` object in your loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common issue: to find element inside each `tweets.get(i)` you should specify dot which stands for current node (context) in the beginning of XPath:

```
".//div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/small/a/span"  # first node found inside current tweet
```

instead of

```
"//div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/small/a/span"  # first node found in DOM
```