# how can I get all the information successively using driver.find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I tried to extract all this information but the result obtained is except the first block of:
  driver.find_elements_by_xpath ("// article [contains (@class, 'dual block block')]")
but I need all, how can I do and thank you.

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path = r'/home/twitter/geckodriver')
    driver.get('https://www...')
    d = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[contains(@class, 'bi-bloc blocs')]")

    for article in d :
            name = article.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'denomination-links')]")
            if name is not None :
                print ("####1#####")
                print (name.get_attribute("title"))
            logo = article.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src, 'data:image/png;base64')]")
            if logo is not None :
                print ("####2#####")
                print (logo.get_attribute("data-pjlazyload").replace('{"effect":"fadeIn", "src":"',"http:").replace('?w=140&h=140&crop=1"}',''))
            adresse = article.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'Voir le plan')]")
            if adresse is not None :
                print ("####3#####")
                print (adresse.text)
            desc = article.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'activites pj-lb pj-link')]")
            if desc is not None :
                print ("####4#####")
                print (desc.text)
            prest = article.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'cviv cris')]")
            if prest is not None :
                print ("####5#####")
                print (prest.text)
            num = article.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[contains(@class, 'num')]")
            if num is not None :
                print ("####6#####")
                print (num.get_attribute("title"))
            time = article.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'value')]")
            if time is not None :
                print ("####7#####")
                print (time.text)
```

Comment: Without being able to look at the HTML source you're trying to extract information from it's hard to assess how to help you.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926794/getting-webelement-while-using-another-webelement/48927022#48927022) to solve your problem (just put the dot in the beginning of each relative XPath query)